# Application Exits and then Hangs in Console

Tags: c++, gcc, wxwidgets

I have a GUI application and I use GCC in Ubuntu Linux to build it. The application builds correctly and runs correctly. The problem is, when I Quit the Application via Menu it Exits but hangs on console/terminal until I force it with Ctrl+C.

Here is my code ( I have stripped big part as it is saving stuffs)

```
void MainFrame::OnQuit(wxEvent& e)
{
    Destroy();
    delete m_pluginManager;
}
```

AFAIK [Destroy() is supposed to destroy all children](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_close_event.html) and the window disappears (which to me means it have been destroyed) But something seem to hang there

I have tried as one friend suggested below to run under GDB and when it hangs I do Ctrl+C and use backtrace but I cannot understand the BT either. Here it is

**BACKTRACE**

```
0xb7fdd424 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
#1  0xb6f5cdcb in poll () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:81
#2  0xb66952db in g_poll () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#3  0xb66866d0 in ?? () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#4  0xb6686831 in g_main_context_iteration ()
   from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#5  0xb2351e80 in ?? ()
   from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libdconfsettings.so
#6  0xb66abfc3 in ?? () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#7  0xb7034d78 in start_thread (arg=0xb21ffb40) at pthread_create.c:311
#8  0xb6f6c3de in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/i386/clone.S:131
```

My GCC version (if matters)

```
 gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.7/lto-wrapper
Target: i686-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.3-1ubuntu1' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.7/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,go,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.7 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.7 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --enable-objc-gc --enable-targets=all --with-cloog --enable-cloog-backend=ppl --disable-cloog-version-check --disable-ppl-version-check --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=i686-linux-gnu --host=i686-linux-gnu --target=i686-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.7.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.3-1ubuntu1)
```

NOTE:I have done some edits to reflect status quo of the problem

Comment: If the application is not exiting then it means it is still doing something, as if your event loop had not exited, only the window having been hidden. More code, like how you're exiting, would be interesting to see.

Comment: updated. the code is massive but I included the part that does the real quit!

Comment: Would one tell me why I got upvote? is there something unclear? Is it irrelevant? or what?

Comment: I updated. The tags says wxWidgets :)

Comment: Even though I didn't downvote, it is understandable since your assumption about GCC having a "don't quit but pause the program" flag is baseless.

Comment: why do you think its baseless? Program saves all settings, destroys all windows and pauses. Plus I have stated clearly that I read somewhere of this issue and the guy suggested adding switch to GCC. Only problem is I cannot locate the link to that article. Still searching it!

Comment: You need to show more code. Notably, which event did you connect this `OnQuit()` to.

Comment: it is a close event(EVT_CLOSE). All works except that after Quiting the app seems to pause. until I kill it, manually

Comment: @Stefano adding code to pause is not the job of the compiler, but if it existed, it would be added by the C++ runtime library that executes initializers and finalizers around the main() function. Anyways, to see where the thing is paused, just use GDB, let the program execute normally, and at the end, when paused, press CTRL+C, and use the `backtrace` command to see exactly where you are.

Comment: Now this comment is very helpful. Let me do it and see what is pausing it!

Comment: I have tried but I cannot understand the BT. Can you help me translate!

Answer (score 1):

[Here's](http://www.wxwidgets.org/docs/tutorials/hello.htm) the Hello World for wxWidgets.

The canonical quit handler would be this:

```
void MainFrame::OnQuit(wxCommandEvent& WXUNUSED(event))
{
    Close(true);
}
```

Comment: I understand that, but in my case I need to handle wxCloseEvent myself and docs says Destroy() is supposed to do the Job see http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_close_event.html